# Image transferring from Android to python socket issue

Tags: java, android, python, android-studio

I'm trying transfer image from **android** client to **python** server , but i have a problem , the image sent successfully but there are some change in size , the image received will be like :

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTjBl.png)

from size 6Mb to 60Kbyte!
my **Java** (client) look like this :

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
bos.flush();
byte[] array = bos.toByteArray();

OutputStream out = photoSocket.getOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(out);

dos.writeInt(array.length);
dos.write(array);

dos.flush();
dos.close();

photoSocket.close();
```

and the server code **Python**:

```
import socket
import struct
address = ("xxx.xxx.x.x", 9200)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(address)
s.listen(1000)


client, addr = s.accept()
print('got connected from', addr)

buf = b''
while len(buf)<4:
buf += client.recv(4-len(buf))
size = struct.unpack('!i', buf)
print("receiving %s bytes" % size)

with open('tst.jpg', 'wb') as img:
    while True:
        data = client.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        img.write(data)
print('received, yay!')

client.close()
```

Comment: What's the output? How many bytes does the client say it's sending?

Answer (score 0):

you convert images to bytes using method makes you have to **compress** them using `bitmap.compress` in this line :

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
```

try to change this method to :

```
int size = bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);
bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer);
byteArray = byteBuffer.array();

// ... etc
```

I hope this helps.